# How does the brain react to intermittent fasting during the whole cycle?

Tags: nutrition, brain, fasting, energy

In the 16/8 intermittent fasting, you eat for 8 hrs then fast for 16hrs. I am curious about how the brain reacts to these changes as the cycle progresses through the day. When will cognitive performance take a hit and why? When will it be at its optimal and why? What can be done to ensure there isn't a drop in performance at anytime?

I did try to research but only found information about how intermittent fasting helps brain growth. I didn't find any resource tackling cognitive performance. I googled: brain performance fasting, low cognitive performance fasting, intermittent fasting and the brain, hoe intermittent fasting affects your brain.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require questions here to demonstrate some degree of prior research . *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: I did try to research but only found information about how intermittent fasting helps brain growth. I didn't find any resource tackling cognitive performance.

Comment: I googled: brain performance fasting, low cognitive performance fasting, intermittent fasting and the brain, hoe intermittent fasting affects your brain.

Comment: I edited your question and added the information you provided in comments. In the future, when you need to add additional information to a question (or answer), please edit the question and add it there. Everything needed to understand your question should be in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: Thank you @CareyGregory